# How do I formulate this SQL query?

Tags: sql, mariadb

So the question I'm tasked with is "Write the SQL query on the table VEHICLE that lists for each owner the OwnerID, OwnerName, and the number of vehicles each owner owns, sorted by the number of vehicles each owner owns (in ascending order.)"

Here are the Create and INSERT Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle
(
 VehicleID double NOT NULL,
 VehicleType VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 Make   VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
 OwnerID  double NOT NULL,
 OwnerName  VARCHAR(200),
 CONSTRAINT vehicle_pk PRIMARY KEY(VehicleID)
);

INSERT vehicle(VehicleID,VehicleType,Make,OwnerID,OwnerName)
VALUES (111,"Car","Ford",01,"Pam"),
        (222,"Car","Ford",01,"Pat"),
        (333,"Truck","Honda",03,"Pam"),
        (444,"Car","Honda",01,"Pam"),
        (777,"Car","Honda",04,"D.B"),
        (999,"Car","BMW",04,"D.B"),
        (4444,"Car","BMW",11,"Jim");
```

Here is my attempt which gets an error at the very last line:

```
   SELECT OwnerName,
OwnerID,
sum(OwnerID) AS num_of_vehicle,

FROM vehicle
ORDER BY  num_of_vehicle ASC;
```

Comment: You need a `group by`

Comment: hey thanks I still get an error if I do that

Comment: And rethink the use of `sum()` -- is summing the owner IDs really ***count**ing*?

Comment: What is the error message? I can see what's wrong and I believe the error message will give you a clue.

Comment: Oh and tell your instructor to think about normalization of the schemas they present their students. They might get used to really bad practices otherwise...

Comment: @SamM "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDb server for the right syntax to use near "FROM vehicle GROUP BY num_of_vehicle" at line 5"

Comment: @stickybit ah yes i guess i should use "count ()"?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `GROUP BY OwnerName, OwnerID` above the ORDER BY
2. Change the `SUM` to `COUNT`

I wish to point out that your test data might be confused. You have an OwnerID 01 which is variably Pam/Pat. 03 is Pam too, but that could be legit

Comment: epic yea thanks this works, The teacher had pam as 03 as well so well see

Comment: It’s probably to have two different people (different id) both called Pam to catch people out - if you just group by name you’ll get the wrong counts because the two Pam people will merge together. If you group by name and id then they will remain separate